# Recording Tests in TestCafe using PIV Card Technbology

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

Using TestCafe, when running a test suite that already exists, and includes a signin function that clicks through and works successfully using PIV Card authentication and code that was written manually all works well. However, in the essence of speed, I was hoping to record tests using the TestCafe Studio software to get it done quicker than manually doing it.The issue we are running into, if I click "record a new test" on an existing test script, it attempts to run through the existing signin code, (which works if you run it as a normal test executing and not recording), it fails on logging in. I believe it's due to the nature of PIV. I was wondering, is it possible with testcafe studio, a setting perhaps that might maintain state of a logged in session rather than killing it at each test start? I'm already logged in with my PIV when I start the test, but it's appearing to log me out at the start of each session. Anyone have experience with this and know what I can do to make it remember me when I run a new test?

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand your usage scenario, you are running tests using a user profile, which is already logged in. Unfortunately, TestCafe Studio does not have a mechanism for launching recording with profiles, as well as launching a browser with any options in general.

I can suggest you the following workaround:

1. Turn off the code responsible for the login when recording the script.
2. Use the `await t.debug()` function instead of login.
3. When the test starts, wait for the debug panel to appear in the browser and unlock the page:
   [image]
4. Sign in manually.
5. Click `Resume` on the debug panel.
6. Write down your script.
7. Replace `await t.debug()` with a login function.